# QEMU not installing

Tags: 20.04, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, postfix, qemu

So I wanted to install QEMU on my Windows laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-i86 -y
```

and I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package qemu-system-i86
```

I tried lots of different versions such as qemu,  qemu-system, qemu-system-x86_64 and guess what?
**NONE OF THEM WORKED**
So, how can I fix this?
(btw im running wsl)
I've tried using `apt policy qemu-system-*` but it dosen't work.

Comment: `apt policy qemu-system-*` will give you all known packages starting with `qemu-system`.

Comment: nope dosent work

Answer (score 0):

The `qemu-system-i86` isn't available in apt.

Please try and install `qemu-system`

Comment: I tried but, it didn't work. `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package qemu-system is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qemu-system' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Please try a `apt update`. If this doesn't help, please post result from `apt policy qemu-system-*` as mentioned by @Jos

Comment: It would likely help your audience if you could provide complete syntax for the installation commands: apt update && apt install qemu-system-common

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
E: Unable to locate package qemu
```

just call

```
sudo apt update
```

to update package list, then the

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
```

works nice.